# Using openssl s_client to get a file from an https server from the command line

Tags: openssl, file-transfer

I have a file hosted on an https server and I'd like to be able to transfer it to my client using `openssl s_client` as follows: `openssl s_client -connect <my_ip:my_port>/my_file`.

I'm able to currently get the contents of the file by running that command and then typing `GET my_file`, but I'd like to automate this so that it's not interactive. Using the `-quiet` switch doesn't help either.

Note: the device I'm trying to use this on doesn't have any other file transfer programs, so I'm stuck with `openssl`

Comment: Seriously, no wget or curl? That's a shame

Answer (score 3):

If you really can use HTTP/0.9 then this will work for you

```
printf '%s\r\n\r\n' 'GET my_file' | openssl s_client -connect <my_ip:my_port>
```

Comment: Why should they use HTTP/0.9? Is it really that hard to add a host header? `printf 'GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' / www.google.com | openssl s_client -quiet -connect www.google.com:443`

Comment: @User414777 of course it's not hard to add a host header. Or a protocol indicator. The OP said that a plain unadorned `GET` was sufficient, which in these days surprised me. Please re-read their question

Comment: It is sufficient with some servers, like google's. But to get the data, you should use at least `-ign_eof` (or `-quiet`). And probably `-verify_return_error` and `-servername`, if you're really about using TLS ;-)

Comment: With newer version of OpenSSL, `-servername` takes its value from `-connect` by default.  So `-servername` may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`openssl s_client` is not a particularly great tool for this, but it can be done.  Let's break this down into two parts.  First, making the HTTP request, and second, extracting your content from the response.

#### Making the HTTP request

The hardest part here is that `s_client` closes the connection when its stdin gets closed.  So you need to keep stdin open until the connection is closed.  Based on [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/731232/how-can-i-use-openssl-to-get-results-from-http-get-requests), you can do something like:

```
(printf "GET $PATH HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $HOST\r\n\r\n"; sleep 10) | \
    openssl s_client -connect $HOST:443 -quiet) > /tmp/output.tmp
```

There are some big limitations here.  First is that you need to set the time for `sleep` long enough that the transfer can complete.  But not so long that you wait forever.  Second is that there's no redirect handling, so you need a URL that will serve the data directly on the URL you request rather than `302`ing you off somewhere else.

#### Extracting the data

Now you have a `/tmp/output.tmp` that has the HTTP response in it, which includes your data *and* some headers.  Stripping the headers is harder than it sounds, because you may have a mixture of `\r\n` and `\n` newlines, and you may be transferring binary data.

If your file is Unix style text (e.g., a shell script), then you can get rid of all the `\r` characters and remove everything up to and including the first blank line:

```
tr -d '\r' < /tmp/output.tmp | sed '1,/^$/d' > /tmp/output
```

If your file is binary (e.g., an executable), then you can't just delete the `\r` characters.  Assuming the first few bytes of your file are fairly unique (let's say `\xF7ELF` in this example), and assuming you have GNU grep available, you can do something like this:

```
SKIP=$(grep -aboF "$(printf "\xf7ELF")" output | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $1}')
dd ibs=1 if=/tmp/output.tmp of=/tmp/output skip=$SKIP
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this for dl a file stored in a AWS S3 (because I'm on a docker image I can't modify which doesn't have curl installed). But I don't manage to dl the file

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why finding the first CRLFCRLF would fail to separate the file content from the headers if the HTTP standard [requires](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7230.html#page-19) that the header block should be separated from the body by CRLF and even when there are no headers, the first line should also have CRLF at the end? In this case should this work for any file content: `LANG=C grep -boazP -m 1 '\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a' /tmp/my-file | head -1 | awk -F ':' '{print $1 + 4}'`?